# Accept Prepaid Card PayPal REST API

Tags: rest, paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway

as the questions implies, I am in the process of deciding on a payment gateway solution for an online financial service. The gateway should allow customers to pay using prepaid cards without providing a phone number, address, legal name, etc. Ideally the gateway will also allow instantaneous access to cleared payments, but this feature is less important. Will PayPal meet either of these requirements when using the REST API and the direct payment system? I was unable to find a concrete answer in the documentation. If not, are there any competing payment processors which offer support for charging prepaid cards without identify verification? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off topic because you're asking for a recommendation of a payment processor. But from the description you're probably actually looking for Bitcoin and not a payment gateway...

Comment: To help, the service I am providing will allow users to buy cryptocurrencies with fiat currencies...

Comment: I see. Never mind then :-P

Comment: To reiterate my main question, does anyone know whether or not the PayPal REST API allows prepaid cards to be charged directly without any additional information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, no U.S based payment processors allow processing prepaid cards without some form of identifying information about the customer, and PayPal is no exception. However, a representative from PayPal mentioned that a feature allowing anonymous payment has been requested by many merchants and is in development.